# How to include a double quotes mark into RegEx exclusion group in Excel UDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, regex, macros

With help of this [Is there an Excel formula to identify special characters in a cell?](https://superuser.com/questions/660692/is-there-an-excel-formula-to-identify-special-characters-in-a-cell) VBA code and excel UDF, I am checking special characters in my csv file. Using this formula:

```
=RegExCheck([@ItemTitle],"[^\s,'.()!&%A-Za-z0-9é–_/©™®°¼½¾⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞•-]")
```

I am able to add whatever character I like to exclude in this part

`[^\s,'.()!&%A-Za-z0-9é–_/©™®°¼½¾⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞•-]`

However, it is not accepting a double quotation mark `"` in any order. How to add `"` in this

`[^\s,'.()!&%A-Za-z0-9é–_/©™®°¼½¾⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞•-]`

exclusion group in excel UDF.

`[^\s"A-Za-z0-9é_/©™®°¼½¾⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞•-]` with a double quote mark is working fine in https://regexr.com/ in starting positions but not working in `excel 2019 (365)` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- Use the character twice (`""`)
- Use the Unicode encoding of the character : `\u0022`

Comment: Thank you. I confirm your both suggestions are working.