# How to flag all rows in a column that contain special characters but allow commas in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I [found an old post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/660692/is-there-an-excel-formula-to-identify-special-characters-in-a-cell) where the user was trying to flag all rows in column A that contained special characters. One of the answers included a conditional formatting solution:

> `=SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<48)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<>45))+SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>57)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<65))+SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>90)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<97)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<>95))+SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>122)*1)`

This formula checks each character of each filename and determines if its ASCII code is outside the allowable character values. Allowable characters include (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, underscores, and dashes).

My need is *almost* exactly the same except I also need to allow commas, and I’m not talented enough to figure out how to modify the code to allow such. Is there someone who can help?

Comment: What spreadsheet application?  How does your use case relate to the one in the other question (also dealing with filenames, or some other text where certain characters aren't allowed)?  Is the only difference in the exceptions a comma?  In your case, is comma an allowable or nonallowable character?  If it is allowable, did you try just adding it to the character list?

Comment: Spreadsheet app is Excel. All the same characters should be allowed plus, in my case, I would also like to allow commas. I'd like to use the solution now showing in my question -- not quite sure how in this case to add commas to the character list.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've gone back and read the original comment. This formulae should work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<48)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<>45)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<>44))+SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>57)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<65))+SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>90)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<97)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<>95))+SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>122)*1)
```

I've added this bit in the formulae above:

```
(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<>44)
```

`44` is the ASCII equivalent of a `comma`. So, this bit will take care of the `comma`.

---

I see that you changed your question. Can you provide some sample values for `A1`?

I don't quite get the formula you provided - `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))` will always be 1; so I don't know what's the point of calling it.

---

Just change this line from the other link:

```
RegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9_-]"
```

To this:

```
RegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9_\-,]"
```